# mysql rename results?

Tags: mysql

I have this function

```
SELECT LEFT( eventName, INSTR( CONCAT( eventName, ':' ) , ':' ) ) AS prefix, COUNT( * )
FROM trackingevent
GROUP BY LEFT( eventName, INSTR( CONCAT( eventName, ':' ) , ':' ) )
UNION SELECT homeupload, COUNT( * )
FROM link
GROUP BY homeupload
UNION
SELECT mediaType, COUNT( * )
FROM link
GROUP BY mediaType
UNION 
SELECT emailSub, COUNT(*) FROM link WHERE emailSub='1' GROUP BY emailSub
```

and it generates something like

```
prefix  COUNT(*)
CONTEST_ENTRY:  4
EMAIL_SHARE     77
FLICKR_SHARE    9
SHARE_FACEBOOK  105
SHARE_STATION_LOGIN     223
TWEET_SHARE     18
0   320
1   1
image   320
video   1
1   195
```

I want to rename the 0,1 and the other 1 to something else. Maybe homeupload, onsite, or something.

The first 0 and 1 are     UNION SELECT homeupload, COUNT( * )
    FROM link
    GROUP BY homeupload

As there are two values

The second 1 is UNION 
SELECT emailSub, COUNT(*) FROM link WHERE emailSub='1' GROUP BY emailSub

How can I rename the results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in short, using `IF`

```
...
UNION
SELECT IF(homeupload = 0, 
            "someStringDescribingStatus0",
            "someStringDescribingStatus1") as homeUploadStatus,
       count(*)
FROM ...
```